# Что такое TOKEN = ... PYTHON

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не понимаю что это такое, если вызвать print(TOKEN) выдает Ellipsis

Comment: @Сергей, в примере предполагается, что вместо многоточия будет записано какое-то значение. Многоточие в python - это специальный объект класса Ellipsis. Т.к. вы не заменили многоточие ни на что, то многоточие в переменную и запислось.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно `PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code` [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id48) таким образом принято обозначать константы - большими буквами, а слова разделяя нижним подчёркиванием. Дословно:

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.